# PHP Regex correct syntax preg_split after any number of words and 1-3 digits

Tags: php, regex, linux, preg-match, preg-split

I'm trying to break down a rss feed with sports scores

**Example data**

```
San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2
Miami 2 Philadelphia 7
Boston 3 Toronto 1
Washington 3 Atlanta 1
Chicago Sox 3 Texas 1
St. Louis 6 Milwaukee 5
```

The rss basically gives me one flowing string like `San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2` and i'm trying to break it down for better use.

Basically im trying to first split `San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2` into four variables, `$home_team`, `$home_score`, `$away_team`, `$away_score`.

But, obviously the home team could be one word or more, the score could be 1 digit or up to 3 so i've been trying to figure out the best regular expression to split this up in the correct format.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

Code that i'm actually using this for, i'm pulling xml of mlb games today, filtering out just the games that are labeled as Final meaning Final Score and then im trying to break it down further from there..

```
<?php





$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.feedburner.com/mpiii/mlb?format=xml");



  foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){

  if(preg_match('/(FINAL)/', $item->title, $matches) || preg_match('/(POSTPONED)/',   $item->title, $matches)){

if(preg_match('/(POSTPONED)/', $item->title, $matches)){
    continue;
}
$string = $item->title;
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\\(FINAL\\)/';
$patterns[1] = '/\\(POSTPONED\\)/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = '';
$replacements[0] = '';
$string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);


 $keywords = preg_match("^(.*?) ([0-9]{1,3}) (.*?) ([0-9]{1,3})$", $string);
 echo $keywords[1]."<br/>";
 }
 }







?>
```

Comment: Check my answer and demo please. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string based on a sequence of digits, assuming that team names don't contain digits as well :)

```
$s = 'San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2';

list($home_team, $home_score, $away_team, $away_score) = array_filter(
  array_map('trim', 
    preg_split('/\b(\d+)\b/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
  ), 'strlen');
```

Comment: This wont work as expected for teams with numbers in their name, for example San Fransico 49ers

Answer (score 0):

This might be exactly what you want:

```
<?php 
$your_input_string ="San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2 Miami 2 Philadelphia 7 Boston 3 Toronto 1 Washington 3 Atlanta 1 Chicago Sox 3 Texas 1 St. Louis 6 Milwaukee 5 ";

$your_result = array_chunk(array_filter( array_map('trim', preg_split('/\b(\d+)\b/', $your_input_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)), 'strlen'),4);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($your_result);
 ?>
```

[Live Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eRBDeM)

Comment: Its in one string at the moment not in an array

Comment: It would be nice to at least upvote the answer that makes up the bulk of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
<?php 
$rssLine="San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2";
//add code to loop though lines
if(preg_match ("/^(.*?) ([0-9]{1,3}) (.*?) ([0-9]{1,3})$/" ,$rssLine, $matches) ===1){

$home_team      = $matches[1];
$home_score     = $matches[2];
$away_team      = $matches[3];
$away_score     = $matches[4];

}
else{
//log no match found
}

?>
```

Match 1 is home team. Match 2 is home score. Match 3 is away team. Match 4 is away score

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array("San Diego 4 Chicago Cubs 2",
    "Miami 2 Philadelphia 7",
    "Boston 3 Toronto 1",
    "Washington 3 Atlanta 1",
    "Chicago Sox 3 Texas 1",
    "St. Louis 6 Milwaukee 5"
);

$results = array();

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $scores = preg_split("/[A-Za-z\s\.]+/", $v);
    $teams = preg_split("/[\d]+/", $v);

    $results[] = "Home: ".$teams[0]." (".$scores[1]."), Away: ".$teams[1]." (".$scores[2].")"; }

foreach ($results as $v) {
    echo $v."<br>"; }
```

Results:

Home: San Diego (4), Away: Chicago Cubs (2)

Home: Miami (2), Away: Philadelphia (7)

Home: Boston (3), Away: Toronto (1)

Home: Washington (3), Away: Atlanta (1)

Home: Chicago Sox (3), Away: Texas (1)

Home: St. Louis (6), Away: Milwaukee (5)

---

You could obviously construct `$results` however you wish; but the meat of the solution is the regexes:

```
$scores = preg_split("/[A-Za-z\s\.]+/", $v);
$teams = preg_split("/[\d]+/", $v);
```